# How to create ROW VALUE index

Tags: index, postgresql-9.4

I have a table, lets call it `mytable`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable {
    id INTEGER,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    ..
)
```

and I have following query in multiple client applications:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable ... ORDER BY (ts, id) DESC;
```

The query is very slow, because of `(ts, id) DESC` ordering, which results in:

```
...
Sort Key: (ROW(t.ts, t.id))
Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 51kB
...
```

in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE ..`

When I remove the parentheses in `ORDER BY` and use `.. ORDER BY ts DESC, id DESC;` in the query, and add `CREATE INDEX idx_mytable ON mytable(ts, id);` it uses the index and it's super fast.

However - as I've said, the original query is in multiple clients and I would rather add one index than change client application and update all clients.

So I would like to create ROW VALUE index - something like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mytable ON mytable(ROW(ts, id));
```

but this is not a valid syntax.

Is there a way to create ROW VALUE index which would be used in query with `..ORDER BY (ts, id) DESC` ?

Comment: The only sensible solution is to get rid of those useless (not to say stupid) parentheses.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree they are stupid (yes, I put them there few years ago - so it is entirely my fault) - but is there really no way to define "composite value/row value" index? I thought that because postgresql is the only DB which fully implements sql:92 row values, there may be some way..

Comment: Did you try: `CREATE INDEX ON mytable((ts, id));`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I did (it says: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","`) , I also tried `(row(ts, id))` and many others but nothing seems to work - also from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html I think it would have to be some kind of expression in order for it to be a valid statement